# Is it possible to use OracleDataSource for some other database except for Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, hsqldb

What I want is to use OracleDataSource with HSQLDB database. Is it possible?

Comment: For standard API - look into JDBC

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. This is why these classes implement interfaces. Both [OracleDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html) and the [HSQLDB DataSource](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCDataSource.html) implement the [javax.sql.DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface so you should use those instead. Then you can swap between them without changing your code at all.

Answer (score -2):

No, it isnt. HSQLDB is an internal database inside Eclipse.

Comment: What has HSQLDB to do with Eclipse?

Comment: I suppose it's possible that [HSQLDB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/) might be *used* in Eclipse, but to imply that it's *only* used in Eclipse is misleading.